# How to remove the 'unexpected Token export' error from serverless project?

Tags: babeljs, serverless-framework

I am creating a project using the serverless framework with es7 support. But i am getting an **unexpected Token export** error when i try to run my function locally using the following command

```
serverless invoke local --f hello
```

I think i have included the required babel dependencies -

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "olep-app-api",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "A starter project for the Serverless Framework with ES7 support",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AnomalyInnovations/serverless-es7.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.94.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.8.2",
    "serverless-webpack": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.14"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-3"]
}
```

**serverless.yml**

```
service: olep-17-api

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

custom:
  webpackIncludeModules: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: prod
  region: ap-south-1

  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-1:*:*"

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var yaml = require('js-yaml');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

var handlerRegex = /\.[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][_$a-zA-Z0-9\xA0-\uFFFF]*$/;
var include = './_webpack/include.js';
var entries = {};

var doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('serverless.yml', 'utf8'));

// Find all the handler files in serverless.yml
// and build the entry array with them
for (var key in doc.functions) {
  var handler = doc.functions[key].handler;
  var entryKey = handler.replace(handlerRegex, '');

  // Add error handling and source map support
  entries[entryKey] = [include, './' + entryKey + '.js'];
}

module.exports = {
  entry: entries,
  target: 'node',
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: __dirname,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    }]
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

**handler.js**

```
export const hello = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS 
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: `Go Serverless v1.0! ${(await message({ time: 1, copy: 'Your function executed successfully!'}))}`,
      input: event,
    }),
  };

  callback(null, response);
};

const message = ({ time, ...rest }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(`${rest.copy} (with a delay)`);
  }, time * 1000)
);
```

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Your `babel` settings may be incorrect. Check the compiled files when you do `sls webpack`. Your compiled files should not be using ES6 imports as they are not compatible with Node v6.10.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error and it is non-descriptive.  I believe it means an exception is being thrown that is not being caught.  It also appears when there is a runtime syntax error, like using an undefined variable.  Here is my workflow which is different than yours but allows me to set a breakpoint and step through the code.  From this I can identify the bad line.

Install serverless-offline so you can run your project locally.  Install Visual Studio Code so you have an IDE to debug in.  I have posted my launch.json to [Breakpoints not being hit when debugging Serverless in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46668483/breakpoints-not-being-hit-when-debugging-serverless-in-vscode)  Set a breakpoint then hit your enpoing with a browser or curl.