# Breakpoints not being hit when debugging Serverless in vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, serverless-framework

None of my breakpoints are active when debugging my serverless based application in VSCode.

launch.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "name": "Debug",
     "port": 5858,
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run-script",
        "vscode:debug"
      ],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "type": "node"
    }
  ],
  "version": "0.2.0"
}
```

My package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
  ...      
  "vscode:debug": "export SLS_DEBUG=* && node --inspect=5858 --debug-brk --nolazy ./node_modules/.bin/serverless invoke local -s local -f customerAlexa -p ./test/requests/FindAgent-First-GoodZip.json"
},
....
```

When I choose Start Debugging from the menu, all the red breakpoints go grey and the program just executes without stopping on the breakpoints.

[image: DebugMenu]

I am running Node 6.11.2, Serverless 1.23.0 on a Mac.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my launch.json which allows me to use breakpoints.

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/serverless",
  "args": [
    "offline",
    "start",
    "--skipCacheInvalidation"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  }
}
```

I am using the serverless-offline to run locally.  I also am using webpack and babel.  The  `skipCacheInvalidation` is for that.

I hope this points you in the right direction.